# How to handle multiple AWS AppSync service versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, versioning, serverless-framework, aws-appsync

I have an iOS app which works with AWS AppSync deployed through the Serverless Framework. Until then every update to the API were non-breaking changes.

Today I need to make breaking changes to the service. How do I do so without preventing not up-to-date apps from working ?

Do I have to create a new AppSync API for every new version ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the best practice, as of now, would be to create a new API. If you must introduce breaking changes to the API and keep the old version of the API functioning, you can create a new API and point it to the same underlying data sources. If you want to automate the deployment process of multiple environments, you can take a look at this small sample that I have used to start projects in the past [AppSync CI/CD Starter](https://github.com/mikeparisstuff/appsync-ci-cd-starter).

There is a backlog item that addresses schema/api versioning, and I would be interested to hear more about your use case. Is the outcome that you would be able to have 2 "live" versions of the same API? For example, you might hit the old version at xxx.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/graphql while at the same time there is a new version at xxx.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/latest/graphql? Do you have other requirements?

Comment: My use case is pretty common I guess. When I'll publish the new app version, all users won't update immediately (obviously). So the backend can't just ignore them. So yeah v1/v2 sounds good !

Comment: My deployment process is already taken care of by Serverless.